# Neural Networks for hexagon-shaped (and binned) images?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, autoencoder, hexagonal-tiles

This is really a conceptual question -- I've been working on this for sometime now, but haven't found a great way to go about solving my problem. I have a [hexagonal image with hexagonal binning/pixels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cyzg.png), with b/w intensity values for each pixel and am trying to feed this into a deep autoencoder, but it seems as if these use square or rectangular images (with square pixels). *Note this image is given as a 1-D array, with appropriate x,y coordinates*

I've thought and looked into number of ideas to handle this situation, and am looking for some feedback or info that can point me in the right direction.

- Convert the hexagonal image to a cube. This would work if we dealt with all full hexagon pixels, but the half-cells (ie. half hexagons) makes this not possible.
- Slicing hexagon pixels into equal sized pixels (half hexagons) so we can feed them in as "square" pixels. However, the orientation of the half-hexagons prove this to be a challenge. I also thought about slicing the pixels this into smaller triangle pixels, but then I wouldn't know how to deal with this.
- Adding white pixels (ie. all 0s) and forcing the image to look like a rectangle or square. However, I wouldn't know the relation between square and hexagonal pixels.
- Transforming hexagon pixels to square pixels, then adding white spaces such that the hexagon image becomes a rectangular image. This seems to be the most probable, and I'm currently reading articles on how to do this, but I'm not sure how to properly handle the half-hexagon pixels.

I guess the generalized question is --

> how do I deal with feeding an image into a Neural Network when the
> image is both non-rectangular shaped and non-rectangular pixeled?

Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problems with resampling it with a regular square grid, so that it becomes a proper 2D image. You would likely need to do it in any case to keep the network size reasonably small.

Comment: Ah okay, but with the half-pixels, would I represent their data values as half the intensity, or will the geometry be invariant given the fact the autoencoder just wants to reproduce the same values?

I'm attempting to apply a CNN to it, with pooling.

Comment: @Kai, to each square pixel assign whatever value is at the location on your hexagonal grid that corresponds to the centre of that pixel. It's like taking a photo.

Comment: Hi Don -- okay, but then how do I deal with the non-rectangular image. What is in the hexagonal outline from the link above is what the image is actually (the other stuff that makes the image a square is just an overlay the artist drew). The tensors used in the autoencoder are non-rectangular, which I think is impossible for matrices.